# Is there a Delphi obfuscator that works for >= Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, obfuscation

I used to use Pythia to obfuscate my D6 program. But it seems Pythia does not work anymore with my D2007.
Here's the link of Pythia (no update since early 2007) : http://www.the-interweb.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/86-Pythia-1.1.html

From link above, here's what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: Why would one want to do this? Surely the user can see all the information in the .dfm files when they run the app.

Comment: why not to get source and patch it?

Comment: I want to obfuscate string including procedure name etc. Pythia can do it automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Over the course of time, a lot of new language features were added.

Since there is no formal grammar available, it is very hard for tool vendors (including Embarcadero themselves) to keep their Delphi language parsers up at the same level as the Delphi Compiler.

It is one of the reasons it takes tool vendors a bit of time (and for Delphi generics support: a lot of time!) to update their tools, of they are update at all.

You even see artifacts of this in Delphi itself:

- the structure pane often gets things wrong
- the Delphi modelling and refactoring sometimes fails
- the Delphi code formatter goes haywire

Pythia is the only obfuscator for the native Delphi language I know of.
You could ask them on [their site](http://www.the-interweb.com/serendipity/) if they plan for a newer version.

Personally, I almost never use obfuscators for these reasons:

- reverse engineering non-obfuscated projects is difficult enough (it would take competitors long enough to reverse engineer, so the chance to lessen the backlog they already have in the first place is virtually zero)
- their added value is limited when you have multi-project solutions (basically they only hide internal or private stuff)
- they make bug hunting production code far too cumbersome

--jeroen

Comment: I can't express my words easily in English. The point is if someone/competitor use Dede or any decompiler to open my program, they got nothing useful strings to read. I use many friendly name modules and many external modules, that's why I need Pythia. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Even with that 'readable' information, it takes a competitor a long time to redo what you are doing. In the mean time, you can continue to add more features to your app at a speed they cannot reverse engineer. So they get behind even further.

Comment: +1 here. I've never understood why anyone would bother obfuscating their code when it often takes the developer some time to understand their own code after they leave it for a while. I have a publicly available framework of some 60,000 lines of code and even though I have been working on it for 10 years on and off, I still have trouble understanding some of the code I wrote and why I wrote it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You may try [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) - Ultimate Packer for Executable).  It will compress the resources and all the text entries are non-readable without de-compress first.

Comment: Uhm, but it is so easy to unpack UPX, even using Olly. For other packers, I don't like to see battle between packer vs Antivirus.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any good free solutions, but if you really need some protection you can always buy something like:

http://www.aspack.com/asprotect.html

or

http://www.oreans.com/themida.php