# When and how should I obfuscate my Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, obfuscation

What should I know about code obfuscation in Delphi?

Should I or shouldn't I do it?

How it is done and is there any good tools (commercial/free) to automate it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why would you need to?

As a whole Delphi does not decompile back, unlike .net, so, while decompilation is always a bit of a risk, Ive never found a decompiler that actually did it to a useful way, lots of areas got left as assembler and so on.

If people want to rework your work, they can, no matter what, obfuscation or not, heck, some coders write almost naturally obfuscated code (having worked with a few)

My vote therefore, is shouldnt bother. Unless someone can show me a decompiler for delphi that really works, and produces full sets of compilable, and all delphi where it was originally, I wouldnt worry one drop.

Comment: @BugFinder I want my software make harder to crack not to protect my code. I mean if I just have one method to check serial then it's easy to crack it so I want to obfuscate code to make it a little bit harder. Is it right?

Comment: It is too easy to break, at the machine code level, your attempts of obfuscating the code at the source level. You might want to look at packers that encrypt your binary, and protect it from being executed under a debugger, but there is practically no protection scheme that remains uncracked for long. Even the smallest utilities are cracked within days after release -- it is a sports, or subculture, discipline. You just end up fighting very capable crackers, running out of resources. The more you try to protect, the more they will invest.

Comment: @justme If you want to secure your code against crackers, then ask that question instead. That's not what you asked about!

Comment: @mj2008 I'm sorry, I thought that code obfuscation it's a one of the ways to protect my software against crackers :( I mean: http://vmpsoft.com/support/user-manual/introduction/analyzing-cracking-and-protecting-software/

Comment: Yes, @JustMe, it might be *one* way. What you did here is called an *XY problem*.

Comment: With delphi, frankly code obfuscation wouldnt change the end exe as much as you would want... as it will compile up and do the same job. You would need to try a lot harder..

Comment: It's ironic that a problem in .NET (reflector recreates sources from the bytecodes) could eventually come full circle to people wanting to solve a problem that doesn't exist in native code compiled tools.

Comment: Warren, you made me smile.  Yes, yes it is :)

Answer (score 7):

[Pythia](http://www.the-interweb.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/86-Pythia-1.1.html) is a program that can obfuscate binaries (not the source) created with Delphi or C++ Builder. [Source code for Pythia is here](https://github.com/sporst/Pythia).

**Before**:[image]

**After**:
[image]

Comment: @JustMe, this software not works in recents versions of Delphi. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467270/is-there-a-delphi-obfuscator-that-works-for-delphi-2007)

Answer (score 6):

There's no point obfuscating since the compiler already does that for you.

There is no way to re-create the source code from the binary.

And components can be distributed in a useful way without having to distribute the source code.

So there usually is no (technical) reason for distributing the source code.

Comment: JustMe might think distributing source code is mandatory for his case, and he wants to hide "teh codez".

Comment: @TheBlastOne Geez, I'm just a Delphi noob, that's all

Comment: Would You be so kind and point me to more information about Delphi compiler?

Comment: @JustMe, did not want to offend. Now tried to make up for any impoliteness by adding more details to David's answer (visible as soon as it is peer-reviewed positively).

Answer (score 6):

You could do other things to reduce an attacker's ability to disable your software activation system, for example, but in a native-compiled system like Delphi, you can't recreate source code from the binaries.  Another answer (the accepted one at the moment) says exactly this, and someone else pointed out a helpful tool to obfuscate the RTTI information that people might use to gain some insight into the internals of your software.

You could investigate the following hardening techniques to block modification of your system, if that's what you really want:

1. Self-modifying code, with gating logic that divides critical functions of your code such as software activation, into various levels of inter-operable checksums, and code damage and repair.
2. Debug detection. You can detect debuggers being used on your software and attempt to block the software from working in this case.
3. Encrypt the PE binary data on disk, and decrypt it either at load time, or just in time before it runs, so that critical assembler code can not be so easily reverse engineered back to assembly language.

As others have stated, hackers working on your software do not need to restore the original sources to modify it. They will attempt, if they try it at all, to modify your binaries directly, and will use a detailed and expansive knowledge of assembler language to circumvent things you may wish them not to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free [JCF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedicodeformat/?source=pdlp) (Jedi Code Formatter) to obfuscate your source code. However, pascal syntax does not allow strong obfuscation and JCF even doesn't do it's best (well, it's a code formatting tool, not obfuscator!)