# Prevent debug information for array of enumerated type from appearing in EXE

Tags: delphi

I open up the Delphi IDE and create a new project.  Here's the whole code for the application:

```
program EnumSymbolsInExeTest1;

type
  tMyEnum = ( A );

begin
end.
```

I build the application, and then search the EXE for "`tMyEnum`".  It is found.  That's no surprise because I have Debug Information set ON in the Linker options.

I turn off Debug Information. I rebuild.  I search the EXE again and now there is no mention of `tMyEnum`.  So far everything is as expected.

Then I change the code. I add a variable.

```
program EnumSymbolsInExeTest1;

type
  tMyEnum = ( A );

var
  Z : tMyEnum;

begin
end.
```

I rebuild.  Still no surprises.  I get a hint for an un-used variable, and the EXE still has no mention of `TMyEnum`.

Then I make another small change:

```
type
  tMyEnum = ( A );

var
  Z : array of tMyEnum;

begin
end.
```

I change the variable to an array.  I rebuild.  I search the EXE and find that "`tMyEnum`" now appears in the EXE file.

My questions are:  Why?

And how can I stop it?  I don't want any of my internal identifiers to appear in the executable file I send to my customers.

I am using Delphi 10.2

In response to David Heffernan, I've added these compiler directives.

```
program EnumSymbolsInExeTest1;

{$WEAKLINKRTTI ON}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([]) PROPERTIES([]) FIELDS([])}

type
  tMyEnum = ( A );

var
  Z : array of tMyEnum;

begin
end.
```

My EXE still contains "tMyEnum".

I have a new clue!  I changed the array from dynamic to static.

```
program EnumSymbolsInExeTest1;

type
  tMyEnum = ( A );

var
  Z : array [1..10] of tMyEnum;

begin
end.
```

Now the identifier no longer appears in the EXE.

So the declaration of the type does not trigger it, adding a variable of that type does not trigger it, adding a static array does not trigger it, but making it a dynamic array does.

Comment: Disable rtti and then try again

Comment: @David Heffernan, I've added these compiler directives.  Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: What happens when you make it a fixed array? Or defining a type of this array instead of a variable? Does it happen for other types than just enums?

Comment: Why are you so concerned about this information in your EXE? Since it has no linking with your *private* information (real name, address, bank account etc.) leave it where it is. I believe that most users of your program neither interested nor want to know what is hidden inside your EXE. But if you want you can [use third party program to obfuscate your EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6229721/5581243).

Comment: Your edit explains the reason, DynArraySetLength accepts type information as a parameter to determine required memory.

Comment: As to why I care, ... today we had an issue where a customer's virus software was complaining about our executable.  Turns out that one of our identifiers happened to match one of the signatures they were searching for.  Luckily it was a very simple EXE with a few hundred lines of code. We were able to fix it by changing our identifiers using trial and error.  If the same thing had happened in our million-line app, it would've been nearly impossible.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, I think you've figured it out.

Comment: Well, antiviruses software could trigger for *any* reason while inspecting your EXE. Hard to be 100% sure that you can cover all possible reasons and make your program *clear* for lot of software that will trying to inspect your EXE. Perhaps it is good to notice end user about "false" triggers of antiviruses tools. If your company has strong reputation this notice will be more effective then continous changing identifiers in your program. It is just a little thought ;) Anyway, it seems you got the right answer to your question (I mean Sertac's comment)!

Comment: Signing your executables should make the AV happy :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say it's [not possible.](https://youtu.be/-uYNYd8Uir4?t=7)

---

**Conclusion from direct experimental observation**

Try turning off every option that we can find:

**Compiling**

- Code inlining control: **Off**
- Emit runtime type information: false
- Optimization: true
- Assertions: **false**
- Debug information: No debug information
- Local symbols: false
- Symbol reference info: None
- Use debug .dcus: false
- Use imported data references: **false**
- I/O Checking: **false**
- Overflow checking: false
- Range checking: false
- Assignable typed constants: false
- Complete boolean evaluation: false
- Extended syntax: **false**
- Long strings by default: **false**
- Open parameters: **false**
- Strict var-strings: **false**
- Typed @ operator: false

**Linking**

- Debug information: false
- Include remote debug symbols: false
- Map file: Off
- Output resource string .drc file: false

And the symbol still appears in the `.text` section of the final PE module.

[image]

Comment: That's very thorough!   But what about the question:  Why?  Declaring the type does not trigger it.  Adding a variable does not trigger it.  But making it an array does!  What is special about an array?

Comment: That i don't know. I don't know why the compiler would **insist** on having run-time types. Nor can i explain why sometimes it **wouldn't** have them.

Comment: @DavidDubois the WHY is because dynamic arrays use RTTI about the element type. The RTTI includes the type name, which is why the type name appears in the EXE